# Formatting emails using html

Tags: html, css, email

I need to do the following [formatting](http://i88.photobucket.com/albums/k167/wickedheart08/table.png) in my email as instructed to me. As I've read and searched around, emails are supposed to use html1 to 4 and inline styling and tables. I've tried using inline styling using margins but it's just a pain. It's not working in outlook and I'm just pulling my hair in frustration. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Not all CSS is supported in HTML. See this site http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ which has a list of what is supported or not.

One thing I have done in the past is: make a regular HTML + CSS page. Then using internet explorer  on the "Page" menu there is an option to "send page as email" this should copy the HTML and CSS into outlook for you, then you can use that as your starting point.

Comment: I'm using IE9 and I can't find the "Page" menu

Comment: Use the File menu:
 ·        Press Alt + F on your keyboard
 ·        Click Send
 ·        Choose "Page by email"

Comment: oh now I get it. But the thing is it's supposed to be programmed to mass email so I don't think we can use Outlook to send the email. It was a great idea though

Comment: Don't use outlook to send the email, just copy and paste the HTML/CSS it generated into your own template for a starting point.

Comment: After I did your instructions, it redirected me to outlook to send the message :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're asking for a better way to make emails, and that you know how to do what you need to do and its just getting frustrating dealing with inline code.

Its best if you **don't** inline your styles under development. Just code it like a normal website. And then use this tool to bring the styles inline:

[Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/)

In addition, reference here for things you can and cannot use:

[Email CSS Compatibility](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

PS, here are some good resources for getting started:

[HTML Email Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) <-- code for very custom designs

[Mailchimp Templates](http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/) <-- very complete set of common email layouts

Comment: I think this is going to be a server side system and I'm not sure if it's going to be online so I don't think I can use Premailer. It's a good suggestion though

Comment: @JamsMedalla Not sure what you mean, but I assuming your mistaking Premailer for a service? Usually I have non-inlined and inlined copies in separate folders. (Just copy and paste your code and premailer will give you inlined html). It's just an online conversion tool. +it gives you warnings on css properties that are not supported so it is _very_ useful.

Comment: I guess I was in too much of a hurry to fix the codes that I didn't get to look at the other links at Premailer. I thought they only converted uploaded or hosted sites. Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's better to avoid complex styling in emails. Even if it's sad to say, email clients are still bad in interpreting stylish HTML codes.
Just stay on old-fashioned tables and basic formatting (bold, italic, etc).

If you need graphic awesomeness, I suggest you to use a single, big picture. But only as last resort.